# MVC custom attribute for IP addresses not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my model I have a string property for an IP address.
This can be a v4 or a v6 IP address.
I wanted to validate the input so, with some research on the web, I created this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ISR.CustomValidators
{
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
  sealed public class IsIPaddress : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
  {
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "{0} is not a valid IP address.";

    public IsIPaddress() : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
      return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
      if (value != null)
      {
        Regex rgIP4 = new Regex(@"^(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d\d?|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)$");
        Regex rgIP6 = new Regex(@"^(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))$");

        if (rgIP4.IsMatch(value.ToString()))
        {
          return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        if (rgIP6.IsMatch(value.ToString()))
        {
          return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

    IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> IClientValidatable.GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
      return new[] { new ModelClientValidationIsIPaddress(FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()))     };
    }
  }

  public class ModelClientValidationIsIPaddress : ModelClientValidationRule
  {
    public ModelClientValidationIsIPaddress(string errorMessage)
    {
      ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
      ValidationType = "isipaddress";
    }
  }
}
```

I also created this script file for the client side validation:

```
(function ($) {
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("isipaddress", function (value, element) {
    //if (this.optional(element)) return true;

    return true;
  });

  jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("isipaddress");
}(jQuery));
```

Model:

```
 [IsIPaddress]
 public string Network { get; set; }
```

I have checked the webpage, the scriptfile is on there, also are the Jquery validation scripts, all in the right order.
But it is not working.

Where did I go wrong? What did I do wrong?
What do I need to do to get this working?
Does anyone have a good example on how to create a custom validation attribute?

[EDIT]

As I use a lot of ajax calls I have a function I call after each ajax call to re-init the validation and I placed the AddMethod code in there too.

Now I do see a SPAN is added to the HTML for the validation message, but it is empty.
So, somehow the default error message is not shown.
Did I forget something for that?

Comment: How is it not working? Is it not doing anything? Does it force you to cross the streams, thereby causing every molecule in your body to explode at the speed of light?

Comment: It is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved.

In the validator.AddMethod... I didn't have any code to do the check.
I kind of thought that that would be created automatically from the attribute code.

So, I changed it to this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("isipaddress", function (value, element) {

      var regexV4 = new RegExp('^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$');
      var regexV6 =  new RegExp('^(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))$');

      if (regexV4.test(value)) { return true; }
      if (regexV6.test(value)) { return true;}

      return false;
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("isipaddress");
```

Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember unobtrusive jQuery validation plugin is initialized automaticaly and the problem was that .addMethod call was after initialization and it was to late. You should try to addMethod before validation initialization or clear form validation, add the method and init validation again.